# animated css text not work in tiny slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I work with [tiny-slider](http://ganlanyuan.github.io/tiny-slider/) and [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) and [animate-plus](https://github.com/telmomarques/animate-plus.js/) with this code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <ul class="slide">
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/720x460" alt="">
      <span class="animate-plus caption" data-animations="bounceIn" data-animation-duration="3s">text 1</span>
      <span class="animate-plus caption" data-animations="bounceIn" data-animation-duration="5s">text 1-1</span>
      <span class="animate-plus caption" data-animations="bounceIn" data-animation-duration="8s">text 1-2</span>
    </li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/720x460" alt="">
      <span class="animate-plus caption" data-animations="bounceIn" data-animation-duration="3s">text 2</span>
      <span class="animate-plus caption" data-animations="bounceIn" data-animation-duration="5s">text 2-1</span>
      <span class="animate-plus caption" data-animations="bounceIn" data-animation-duration="8s">text 2-2</span>
    </li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/720x460" alt="">
      <span class="animate-plus caption" data-animations="bounceIn" data-animation-duration="3s">text 3</span>
      <span class="animate-plus caption" data-animations="bounceIn" data-animation-duration="5s">text 3-1</span>
      <span class="animate-plus caption" data-animations="bounceIn" data-animation-duration="8s">text 3-2</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var slider = tns({
  container: '.slide',
  items: 1,
  mode: 'carousel',
  slideBy: 'page',
  autoplay: true,
  mouseDrag: true,
  center: false,
  nav: false
});
```

In action problem is: animate text work only in first slide. i need to play animated text for each slide. how do fix this problem?!

[demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/5vunb8aq/)